# Memcache - как сделать продление жизни

Tags: php, memcache

Как в `memcache` сделать продление жизни элемента? Есть идея делать `replace` с новым значением времени жизни, стоит ли так делать есть ли другой способ? Хотелось бы выслушать чужое мнение.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При использовании расширения `memcache` только `replace`. В расширении `memcached` есть метод [`touch`](http://php.net/manual/ru/memcached.touch.php) который позволяет выставить новое время хранения.